# Automapper Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, automapper, automapper-collections-ef-core

I'm working on a project and I need to map collections. I came across **Automapper.Collection** and am trying to user the class but its all not working. Please I need help. Here is my code.

In my startup class

```
services.AddAutoMapper(cfg => { cfg.AddCollectionMappers(); },typeof(Startup));
```

I also created a class that Inherits from the **Automapper** Profile class here

```
public class UserMappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public UserMappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<PhotoToUpdateDto, Photo>().EqualityComparison((src, dest) => src.PublicId.ToLower() == dest.PublicId.ToLower());
            CreateMap<SocialHandles, SocialHandleDto>().ReverseMap().EqualityComparison((src, dest) => src.Name.ToLower() == dest.Name.ToLower());
        }
    }
```

Anytime I use the mapper, it creates new records in the database instead of updating the already existing. Please I need help.

Comment: And your code which calls the database?

Comment: Hi @Taryosky, please share your code about how to update and what is your model design.

Comment: Thanks for your response guys. I've got a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its because of navigation property in your entity

If you have navigation property ignore them in your Createmap

For example

```
CreateMap<PhotoToUpdateDto, Photo>().EqualityComparison((src, dest) => 
src.PublicId.ToLower() == dest.PublicId.ToLower())
.ForMember(p => p.Photographer , opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume this:

- You have no problem with the mapper (since it still map your object successfully).
- When you get new object to interact with database, a new record created, since your make sure the id mapping was correct.
- You are using EF Core or some kind of ORM to interact with the database

If i was wrong, please just ignore this answer.

Okay, If my assuming was right, that's because automapper always return a new object as result of the mapping process, which is absolutely not tracked by your `DbContext` yet. And then, whenever you interact with that to make some change in the database, an add operation is likely going to happen.

I think you need to add some more information about the block of code that you actually have problem with... which in this case... why the database entry keep created, but not update.